# How to apply keyup() function to different DOM element with different input correctly?

Tags: javascript, jquery, this, apply, bind

I'm trying to limit different min and max input of the day, month and year input of date of birth. However it seems there's something wrong with "this" in the function. May I know what is the correct and good way to write this function? I tried arrow function but it does not work. Should I use bind? Thank you so much!

```
$(document).ready(function () {
 var minMonth = 1;
 var maxMonth = 12;
 var minDay=1;
 var maxDay=31;
 var minYear=1900;
 var maxYear=2019;

 function minMaxDob(minDob, maxDob){
        if($(this).val() > maxDob){
            $(this).val(maxDob);
          }
        if($(this).val() < minDob){
            $(this).val(minDob);
          }
      }

 $("#dob_month").keyup(function(){
    minMaxDob(minMonth,maxMonth);
 });
 $("#dob_day").keyup(function(){
    minMaxDob(minDay,maxDay);
 });
 $("#dob_year").keyup(function(){
    minMaxDob(minYear,maxYear);
 });
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to pass the jQuery object to the minMaxDob like the following, you have to do this because "this" refers to the currently executing function, since you are calling a helper function "this" no longer refers to the DOM object, but to the function minMaxDob:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  var minMonth = 1;
  var maxMonth = 12;
  var minDay=1;
  var maxDay=31;
  var minYear=1900;
  var maxYear=2019;

  function minMaxDob(jqObj, minDob, maxDob){
    if(jqObj.val() > maxDob){
        jqObj.val(maxDob);
      }
    if(jqObj.val() < minDob){
        jqObj.val(minDob);
      }
  }

  $("#dob_month").keyup(function(){
    minMaxDob($(this),minMonth,maxMonth);
  });
  $("#dob_day").keyup(function(){
    minMaxDob($(this),minDay,maxDay);
  });
  $("#dob_year").keyup(function(){
    minMaxDob($(this),minYear,maxYear);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 4):

you forget to pass object.
Every time you call function inside a function, function will read only passed data, not variables or object on top. 
Example:

```
function run(){
x=2;
y=3;
check(x);
//or
check2(x,y);
}
function check(x){
if(x<y){
console.log('in that example you will have a error becouse you are not passing 2nd val')
}
}
function check2(x,y){
if(x<y){
console.log('Yes, x is smaller than Y, we send all necessary data')
}
}
```

Simple ad 'this' and reconstruct your main function.

Your script below with snippet

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
 var minMonth = 1;
 var maxMonth = 12;
 var minDay=1;
 var maxDay=31;
 var minYear=1900;
 var maxYear=2019;

 function minMaxDob(minDob, maxDob,el){
       if(el.val()> maxDob){
            el.val(maxDob);
          }
        if(el.val() < minDob){
            el.val(minDob);
          }
         
      }


 $("#dob_month").keyup(function(){
    minMaxDob(minMonth,maxMonth,$(this));
 });
 $("#dob_day").keyup(function(){
    minMaxDob(minDay,maxDay,$(this));
 });
 $("#dob_year").keyup(function(){
    minMaxDob(minYear,maxYear,$(this));
 });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id='dob_month' type='text'>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help!! :D